# Finding type signatures in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-inference, ghci

I'm playing with [a small server in Haskell](http://www.friendlyvirus.org/miguelnegrao/2014/03/09/making-a-tiny-web-server-in-haskell/).  As an exercise, I am manually adding type signatures.

```
import System.Posix (installHandler, sigPIPE, getFileStatus, fileSize, Handler(..))
import Network (listenOn, accept, PortID(..))
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Data.Binary
import Network.Socket (close)
import Control.Monad (forever, replicateM_)
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.IO (hGetContents, hPutStr, hSetBinaryMode, withFile, hClose, IOMode(..))

...

--here's what I want to add a type signature to
processRequest h = do
    s <- hGetContents h
    let req = takeWhile (/= "\r") $ lines s 
    mapM_ (\x -> putStrLn $ "> "++x) req
    return $ words (head req) !! 1
```

Well there should be an easy way to figure this out, let's see what GHCI's type inference says:

```
Prelude> :l tinyserver.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tinyserver.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> :info processRequest
processRequest :: GHC.IO.Handle.Types.Handle -> IO String
    -- Defined at tinyserver.hs:26:1
```

Man that's a big type.  Ok, let's add it:

```
processRequest :: GHC.IO.Handle.Types.Handle -> [Char] -> IO ()
processRequest h = do
   ...
```

That should do it.  Is GHCI cool with this?

```
*Main> :l tinyserver.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tinyserver.hs, interpreted )
tinyserver.hs:26:19:
    Not in scope:
      type constructor or class ‘GHC.IO.Handle.Types.Handle’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Yuck.  Maybe the name is too long.  Let's try all the child types:

```
processRequest :: IO.Handle.Types.Handle -> [Char] -> IO ()
processRequest :: Handle.Types.Handle -> [Char] -> IO ()
processRequest :: Types.Handle -> [Char] -> IO ()
processRequest :: Handle -> [Char] -> IO ()
```

No, they all give me the same result.

What is the right way to find these types?  GHCI?  Hoogle?  Something else?

Comment: Import `Socket` from `Network.Socket` (or just `Network`) and use that. GHCi shows fully qualified names for names that aren't imported in the current session. Here we can know that `Network.Socket.Types.Socket` isn't imported, since we don't have such a qualified import anywhere.

Comment: @AndrásKovács  I've made the following changes:

`import Network.Socket (close, Socket(..))`

`processRequest :: Socket -> [Char] -> IO ()`

`tinyserver.hs:28:23:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘GHC.IO.Handle.Types.Handle’
                with actual type ‘Socket’`

Comment: You can again see that `Handle` is not imported. `import System.IO` does it. You will probably have an easier time here if you just import whole modules without specifying names. It's not hard to find definitions with Hoogle/GHCi/haskell-mode anyway.

Comment: There is a mismatch between `Socket` and `Handle`. Your `processRequest` is operating on a `Handle` but most `Network.Socket` work with the `Socket` type. You can use the `Network.connectTo` function to get a `Handle` directly or convert any old `Socket` to a `Handle` with `Network.Socket.socketToHandle`.

Comment: I note that your function is named `processRequest`, but your ghci query asks about `processRequests` -- note the plural!

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner, that cleared some things up.  My code had both functions, which made this confusing.

Comment: @AndrásKovács `import System.IO` did it; `Handle` is now a type.  I added `Handle(..)` to the import list to be explicit.  If you want to answer I'll mark it as correct.